# Java 8, Drools 5.x and Drools 7.x

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am using Drools 5.x (drools-compiler 5.2.1.Final, drools-decisiontables 5.4.0.Final, and drools-templates 5.4.0.Final; jbpm-flow 5.1.1.Final, jbpm-bmpn2 5.1.1.Final and with their respective dependencies) for my Java job, I build/run it with Java 1.7.0_21.  My current set up works properly.  I am using a decision table (spreadsheet).

I am able to build/run my project with Java 1.8.0_162 using drools 5.x as described above; however, when the java job runs it loads the decision table (spreadsheet) but it does not fire up any of the rules, I am not getting an exception in the last line that gets executed:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration configuration = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration(props);

KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration(configuration);

DecisionTableConfiguration config = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();

config.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);

kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(spreadsheetFile), ResourcType.DTABLE, config);  // last line executed and then job exists and completes successfully.
```

Prior to the last line getting executed I put some debug logs and they show the following:

> > Properties (props):  {}
> >
> > KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration (configuration): org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration@630cb4a4
> >
> > KnowledgeBuilder (kbuilder):  org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl@239bof9d
> >
> > ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(spreadsheetFile):  [ClassPathResource path='spreadsheet.xls']
> >
> > ResourceType.DTABLE:  ResourceType = 'Decision Table'
> >
> > DecisionTableConfiguration (config):  org.drools.builder.conf.impl.DecisionTableConfigurationImpl@150ab4ed
> >
> > DecisionTableConfiguration (config.getInputType()):  XLS

So I decided to upgrade from drools 5.5.0 to 7.5.0 and use kie-api/kie-ci; I had to do some refactoring because now drools is part of the KIE (Knowledge Is Everything) umbrella, see the code below:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession ks = kc.newKieSession("ksession-dtables");  //stateful session
FactHandle fh = ks.insert(fact);
ks.fireAllRules();
```

....

The packages and rules are loaded into the Knowledge Base but only the first rules fire up and then it stops, do I need to upgrade my decision table (spreadsheet) in order to work for drools 7.5.0 with Java 8?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!!

Comment: I am not having this issue with drools 6.5.0, everything seems to be working properly with drools 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I started using drools 6.5.0 and everything works now.